# Getting replies to a particular tweet via Tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Does anyone know how can I get the replied tweets to a particular tweet via Tweepy? It's so confusing for me, because when I try to retrieve the replies with this code to get the replies to a particular tweet ("status_id"), the result is so strange.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
s = api.search(q=api.get_status("status_id").user.name, since_id="status_id")
```

for example for a tweet with status_id "950489574823940096", it returns 15 statuses, while it has only 6 replies.

Comment: Can you please post the result you are getting?
Check the "in_reply_to_status_id"

Comment: As far as i remember, there is no direct way to achieve that! You will have to do a API Search call then go through the search result looking for in_reply_to_status_id matching your specific tweet!